# Even though I place my script tag just above the ending of body tag, the page loads only after the popup is clicked with okay

Tags: javascript

[image]

Even though I place my script tag just above the ending of body tag, the page loads only after the popup is clicked with okay. what do i do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html lang="en" dir="ltr">  
   <head>   
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <title></title>
   </head> 
   <body>    
    <h1>this is for beginners javascript</h1>   
    <div>  <p>this is a div</p>   </div> 
    <script src="js_notes.js"></script>  
   </body>  
 </html>
```

js_notes.js contains only this one line given below

```
alert('hello world');
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: check out `setTimeout()`

Comment: To make this useful you should include at least which browser(s) you tested this on.

Comment: I tested it using Google Chrome and Safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a couple of things and determine what is best for you.

```
<script async="async" src="js_notes.js"></script>
```

In a nutshell saying *"don't stop browser stuff like rendering the page to process the javascript in js_notes.js"*.  Sometimes also used with the `defer` attribute.  You can read more about these attributes at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

This might not be exactly what you want.  Instead, what you might want to to make sure that your page has loaded and painted.  This function (or the jquery `ready()`) might help.

```
function docReady(fn) {
  if (document.attachEvent ? document.readyState === "complete" : document.readyState !== "loading"){
    fn();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  }
}
```

However, you might want to add a little async pause to give the page a chance to paint.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  alert('hello world');
}, 1 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do ?
The js file will always be read when you load the html. If you want to load the pop up just when you do an event (for instance clicking on the div : this is a div), just use onclick function.

In your js_notes.js :

```
function showpopup() {
  alert('hello');
}
```

If you just want to wait the page to be loaded, you can use window.onload or a timer (setTimeout(showpopup, 1000))

In your html file :

```
<div onclick='showpopup()'>Text Content Here</div>
```

Comment: the problem is i want the popup and the webpage to load at the same time because i have placed the script tag at the last, but instead the page gets loaded only after the popup is loaded and is clicked okay.

Comment: Then you need to do :

window.onload = function() {
  alert('hello');
}

Comment: Nope, it's still not working. the page is not getting loaded until i press okay in popup box

Comment: I have added an image description.

Comment: @adhinarayan: *"the page is not getting loaded until i press okay in popup box"* I think you are misstating the issue. The page surely gets loaded, otherwise the alert wouldn't shown. It seems you want the page content to **render** before the alert is shown.